# SQL Query to find Records companywise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want a query that will display rows of those **COMPANIES** who are giving **theft cover** and **key loss** Having status is **yes**
See the Sample Data below :

```
    addon       status  amt1    amt2    company
    theft cover yes      7       7      comp1
    key loss    yes      2       2      comp1
    theft cover no      NULL    NULL    comp2
    key loss    yes      2      33      comp2
    key loss    yes      1       1      comp3
    theft cover yes     12      22      comp3
    theft cover yes     11      22      comp4
    key loss    no      NULL    NULL    comp4
    theft cover yes     22      55      comp5
    key loss    yes     33      44      comp5
```

My query:

```
SELECT     addon, status, amt1, amt2, company
FROM         test
WHERE     (addon = 'theft cover' OR
                      addon = 'key loss') AND (status = 'yes')
```

Please help me. The above query is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query gives you company names:

```
SELECT company
FROM @Table
WHERE addon IN ('theft cover', 'key loss') AND status = 'yes'
GROUP BY company
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT addon) = 2;
```

- It gets all rows with requiered values (WHERE clause)
- It GROUP BY company names in order to count how many of them are present
- It only keeps companies with a COUNT of DISTINCT values of 2 (='theft cover'+'key loss')

**Output:**

```
company
comp1
comp3
comp5
```

You can then join it with you main table and get each associated rows:

```
SELECT t.addon, t.status, t.amt1, t.amt2, t.company
FROM @Table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT company
    FROM @Table
    WHERE addon IN ('theft cover', 'key loss') AND status = 'yes'
    GROUP BY company
    HAVING COUNT(distinct addon) = 2
) as c
    ON c.company = t.company
-- where t.compny = 'xxx'
-- where at.mt1 = 7 or t.amt2 = t.amt1
-- where ...
;
```

**Output:**

```
addon       status  amt1    amt2    company
theft cover yes     7       7       comp1   
key loss    yes     2       2       comp1   
key loss    yes     1       1       comp3   
theft cover yes     12      22      comp3   
theft cover yes     22      55      comp5   
key loss    yes     33      44      comp5
```

**Sample data:**

```
Declare  @Table table([addon] varchar(20), [status] varchar(3), [amt1] varchar(4), [amt2] varchar(4), [company] varchar(5));

INSERT INTO @Table([addon], [status], [amt1], [amt2], [company])
VALUES
    ('theft cover', 'yes', '7', '7', 'comp1'),
    ('key loss', 'yes', '2', '2', 'comp1'),
    ('theft cover', 'no', NULL, NULL, 'comp2'),
    ('key loss', 'yes', '2', '33', 'comp2'),
    ('key loss', 'yes', '1', '1', 'comp3'),
    ('theft cover', 'yes', '12', '22', 'comp3'),
    ('theft cover', 'yes', '11', '22', 'comp4'),
    ('key loss', 'no', NULL, NULL, 'comp4'),
    ('theft cover', 'yes', '22', '55', 'comp5'),
    ('key loss', 'yes', '33', '44', 'comp5');
```

Comment: how please tell
For Example 
addon column have "PA" and i dont want pa addon in the row

Comment: I don't know what you want to remove from the output... Explain what you need

Comment: I added a couple sample where clause in comment at the end. Choose 1 of them and adapt it in order to get what you need such as record for 1 single company. From here this is basic SQL and where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally avoid the aggregate and the group by unless you need them for some particular reason and just go with a simple straight forward query such as. The below query will return the information you specified and order the results by the company name without the overhead of the aggregate function and group by. While they probably wouldn't make a noticeable difference in this instance, were you dealing with a large table/data-set it could very well hinder your performance.

```
SELECT t.addon, t.status, t.amt1, t.amt2, t.company
FROM test t
WHERE t.addon = 'theft cover' 
  AND t.addon = 'key loss'
  AND t.status = 'yes'
ORDER BY t.company
```

Or like the below, I'm kind of unclear on which you're looking for with your description. The below will return any rows for a company offering theft cover/key loss. The above requires that the company offer both addons.

```
SELECT t.addon, t.status, t.amt1, t.amt2, t.company
FROM test t
WHERE t.addon IN ('theft cover', 'key loss')
  AND t.status = 'yes'
ORDER BY t.company
```